# Rolling Unique Observations in an Unbalanced Panel in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to find the number of unique observations in the past 2 days in an unbalanced panel. My data frame looks something like this:

```
W=matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,2),ncol=3,nrow=16)
W<-as.data.frame(W)
colnames(W)<-c('id1','day','id2')
W
   id1 day id2
1    1   1   2
2    1   2   2
3    1   2   2
4    1   2   2
5    1   3   2
6    1   4   2
7    1   4   2
8    1   5   2
9    2   1   2
10   2   1   3
11   2   2   2
12   2   2   3
13   2   3   2
14   2   4   3
15   2   5   2
16   2   5   2
```

It should look like this when done:

```
   id1  day  id2   n_unique
1    1   1   2     NA
2    1   2   2     1
3    1   2   2     1
4    1   2   2     1
5    1   3   2     1
6    1   4   2     1
7    1   4   2     1
8    1   5   2     1
9    2   1   2     NA
10   2   1   3     NA
11   2   2   2     2
12   2   2   3     2
13   2   3   2     2
14   2   4   3     2
15   2   5   2     2
16   2   5   2     2
```

I would prefer to use the dplyr package if possible, as I am comfortable with the basic syntax. I can do this if the panel was balanced, because I can just do

```
fun<-rollify(~n_distinct(.x),window=2)
W<-W%>%
  group_by(id1,day)%>%
  arrange(day)%>%
  mutate(n_unique=fun(dealer_id))
```

But I am having trouble if the panel is unbalanced, since the window will vary over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each id1 and each day find the id2 that are 1 or 2 days ago and then take n_distinct of those.  Finally convert 0 to NA.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

W %>%
  mutate(n_unique = map_dbl(day, ~n_distinct(id2[day %in% (.x-1:2)])) %>% na_if(0),
   .by = id1)
```

giving:

```
   id1 day id2 n_unique
1    1   1   2       NA
2    1   2   2        1
3    1   2   2        1
4    1   2   2        1
5    1   3   2        1
6    1   4   2        1
7    1   4   2        1
8    1   5   2        1
9    2   1   2       NA
10   2   1   3       NA
11   2   2   2        2
12   2   2   3        2
13   2   3   2        2
14   2   4   3        2
15   2   5   2        2
16   2   5   2        2
```

This can be done with sql by joining W to itself on the indicated condition and using count(distinct ...).  nullif converts 0 to Null which is NA on the R side.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select a.*, nullif(count(distinct b.id2), 0) n_unique
  from W a
  left join W b on a.id1 = b.id1 and b.day between a.day - 2 and a.day - 1
  group by a.rowid")
```

### Note

The input W, from the question, is

```
W <- matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,2), ncol = 3, nrow = 16)
W <- as.data.frame(W)
colnames(W) <- c('id1', 'day', 'id2')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would I modify your code if the date is in datetime format? It was a poor choice for me not to put day in that format in the first place.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Just converted the date using as.numeric